# LXDE and LXQt merging - what's the bottom line?

Tags: desktop-environment, lxde

I've read that LXDE was supposedly switching from GTK to Qt, after an announced merge with LXQt. The LXQt page [says](http://lxqt.org/about/)

> LXQt is the Qt port and the upcoming version of LXDE, the Lightweight Desktop Environment. It is the product of the merge between the LXDE-Qt and the Razor-qt projects

But it seems like there are LXDE releases and LXQt releases happening. So what's the deal? Has this merge happened? Will it happen soon? I don't get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Afaik, developers still maintain both LXDE and LXQt and will continue to maintain LXDE still for the foreseeable future. As some of the developers of both are the same ones, the merge is already happening. The goal is that at some point when LXQt is mature enough and all are happy with it, then LXDE will be abandoned - but that is just a wish, as some people may still decide to maintain LXDE forever despite LXQt status. At the moment no one knows for sure and both are equally supported.

Comment: Can you say something about what that point in time is expected to be?

Comment: I am also interested to get the answer on the commented question!!!